# Why ereg does not work?

Tags: php, regex

I build a registration page with php. I have to check if username have alphanumeric symbols. So I did it:

```
$pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}";

echo "Pattern = $pattern<br>";

echo "Username = $_POST[username]<br>";

echo "res = ";
echo ereg($pattern, $_POST['username']);
```

The last echo does not print! I try to use "hello" as username. it should be right! What is the problem?

Comment: probably because it's deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php *"Warning

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.*

Comment: If the function works it would return an array so echoing it wouldn't work. You should be using `preg_match` and you'll need delimiters.

Comment: plus, make sure your form element holds the name attribute. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with `echo "Username = $_POST[username]<br>";` without single quotation marks around `username`? Also, echo should print something, `ereg` returns either a match length, or `false`. Try something like `if (ereg ($pattern, $_POST['username'], $regs)) {   echo "$regs[0]"; }`

Comment: I could maybe be talked in to "*all_the_key*", but definitely not "*all_key_the*".  I absolutely disagree with this.  It's preposterous and it will not stand... the.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ereg() function is deprecated. Try to use preg_match()

```
print preg_match('|[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}|', 'hello', $matches); 
// true
```

aslo you should wrap "username" with quotes

```
echo "Username = $_POST['username']<br>";
```

Comment: If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. If you want only check match pattern you can remove it.

Comment: It should be done like this: `preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}/', 'hello', $matches); print_r($matches);`

Comment: I try it: echo "res = ";
    echo preg_match($pattern, $_POST['username']); But it is howerver empty

Comment: @stribizhev: I try the code that you posted! The result is the same if I use 'hello' and if I use 'hello@'. If I don't put $matches the result is 0 in both. If I put $matches the result is: Array

Comment: its possible that this part of code even not executed due to `Undefined index: username` in `echo "Username = $_POST[username]<br>";`, wrap username with quotes

Comment: @asgu I edited my code with Username = $_POST['username'] but however it dows not work